# How to load a Gameobject from Json ?Is it possible?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am trying to save the position,rotation and scaling of an object .Along with that can I save the Gameobject itself inside a json.I saved the JSON file in Application.persistentDataPath.Below is my datahandler class

```
  using System;
  using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public class DataHandlers

{
public Vector3 localposinmap;
public Quaternion localrotinmap;
public Vector3 sizeofobj;
public GameObject gameobj;

public DataHandlers(Vector3 localpos, Quaternion localrot, Vector3 objsize,GameObject gobj)

{
    this.localposinmap = localpos;
    this.localrotinmap = localrot;
    this.sizeofobj = objsize;
    this.gameobj = gobj;

}


}
```

After saving the file my JSON string is as follows

```
{

"SaveValues": [
{
  "localposinmap": {
    "x": 0.0237075537443161,
    "y": -0.27374106645584106,
    "z": -0.6681503057479858
  },
  "localrotinmap": {
    "x": 0,
    "y": -0.08031735569238663,
    "z": 0,
    "w": -0.996769368648529
  },
  "sizeofobj": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 1,
    "z": 1
  },
  "gameobj": {
    "m_FileID": -112,
    "m_PathID": 0
  }
},
{
  "localposinmap": {
    "x": 0.09054452180862427,
    "y": -0.273919016122818,
    "z": -0.5062751770019531
  },
  "localrotinmap": {
    "x": 0.0001220703125,
    "y": 0.06480370461940765,
    "z": 0,
    "w": -0.9978980422019958
  },
  "sizeofobj": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 1,
    "z": 1
  },
  "gameobj": {
    "m_FileID": -456,
    "m_PathID": 0
  }
}
 ]
}
```

After reading gameobj: "m_FileID":-456 and "m_PathID":0
Can i read this value back and Instantiate the same Gameobject using the above details?

Comment: You mean creating a mesh? If yes you can not do that with this information

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JsonUtility.ToJson` to change your object into json string and `JsonUtility.FromJson` to get it back. Check [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) for more information. Keep in mind:

> Only plain classes and structures are supported; classes derived from UnityEngine.Object (such as MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject) are not.

Comment: And if you want better results than what JsonUtility provides, use Json Dot Net, which will let you set up your own converters.

Comment: I agree with @Draco18s but it requires adding external library.

Comment: Well, yes. But I don't see why that's a problem. JsonUtility is *very* basic and cannot handle certain kinds of scenarios, such as serializing something like a singleton reference (think about how Minecraft saves block and item information: as a string key to a registry). JsonUtility will mindlessly serialize that singleton thousands of times (and not deserialize at all because the singleton already exists).

Comment: @Dave You mean Unity Engine classes are not supported?...but here I am trying to save vector3 and quaternion which gets saved .Also Gameobject IDs.So if I know the path(it is added in a Gameobject array) where the gameobject is can I load it back with using the above information that is... gameobj": {
    "m_FileID": -456,
    "m_PathID": 0
  }

Comment: Yes, some unity objects like Vector3 or Quaternion are not serializable in Unity. In case of these object you can create your own simple classes like SerializableVector3 and SerializableQuaternion. Check this [forum discussion](https://forum.unity.com/threads/vector3-is-not-marked-serializable.435303/). How are you creating this JSON string? With your own method? If so you should really change to JsonUtility or even better as @Draco18s mentioned Json.NET.

Comment: Also when it comes to serialization take a look at Protocol Buffers which is much better than standard serialization.

Comment: @Dave yes with JSON utility.The above Json is created using JSON utility..But I can save all the quaternion and positions.Why not Gameobjects?If i can suggest a path to game objects.I can load it back.That was my idea.But Gameobjects I believe is tough as all the data like Quaternion and Position are Vector3 which are three strings x,y and z.

Comment: If you check the docs JSON utility allow serialization from plain classes, structures and classes derived from MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject to JSON. It is not possible to do it the other way around. You can deserialize only plain classes and structures. Gameobjects are complex types which can have different components attached.

Comment: Its not trivial to serialize gameobjects, as you can't deserialize them directly, you have to look at the deserialization data and go "ok I need to either find this game object (because its already been deserialized) or create a new one, that will automatically give it a transform, so I shouldn't create one of those, just plug these values in..." and so on. Most of the time you'll want to spawn in a prefab (but which one?) hence why I suggest Json Dot Net.